# Can I get all the comments from an Instergram photo without access token?

Tags: javascript, php, api, instagram

Is this possible to get all the comments from a specific Instagram photo (post url) without access tokens?

for example, this is my photo: https://www.instagram.com/p/BLMEneNBCkw/?taken-by=caseyneistat

Can I manipulate Instagram api (or by not using the api) so it will give me all the comments of this photo without the need of an access token or any kind-of-user-permission thing.
[using PHP or JavaScript]

my first tought was using Jquery(&Ajax) - getting the source code of the url and than using the 'html' function in Jquery in order to get the content (the comment) between every two divs with the id related to the comments.
but this couldn't work because Instagram shows you something like 10 comments everytime and in order to get the next 10 you need to click 'view all..'.

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: You should explain why you want to do it not through the API. There's a reason there are limits on the API and it's not nice to ask how to get around the restrictions that they have put in place

Answer (score 1):

If you use Instagram API (i.e. using access_token), you can only get the latest 150 comments, you cannot get more than that.

So if you want all comments, the link you posted has 900+ comments, the only way to get all is using the instagram link, load all comments and select/copy the comments and paste it in a spreadsheet (i just tried it works)

Answer (score -1):

I think it's doable without api by reading the html and processing datas. Otherwise, you'll need tokens in order to grab details from the photo id.

Sorry for you.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for answering.

As i wrote, I did tried your idea out but Instagram only shows somethink like 10 comments, if you want to see more you have to click a button.

Is there any way to pass this and see all the comment?

Comment: It could be fastidious to make that to get all comments by scrolling. Why can't you use the api with token ? It will simplify you a lot of things, really.